# POST a JSON data on a Server URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, post

I have prepared a JSON data and I need to post it on the server so that a service can be called. URL to the server is available and I am making an AJAX call for the same to 
POST the data.

But I dont know where to place the JSON string that is generated.

My Code is as Follows:

```
function postJSONData(JSONData, localMode)
        {
            var localJSONData = JSONData;
            var postMode = localMode;

             $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://tt.s2.com/tmobile/subscribe-service/uid=ankit_bharat_tanna',
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("SECOND POST JSON DATA");
                    }   // Success Function
    }); // AJAX Call

            alert("POST JSON ------------> "+localJSONData +" "+postMode);
        }
```

I want to post JSON data to the server URL. any Parameters to be used?

Thanks,
Ankit.

Comment: `data : { "requestParamName" : localJSONData }` where `"requestParamName"` is whatever parameter name you are using in your server-side code to receive the JSON.

Comment: Please visit the jQuery [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) doc and scroll down to read about the data setting.

Comment: why `dataType:'xml'` you want to send it xml based or you want to access it?

Comment: I want to sent JSON data to the server.

Comment: what is your variable localJSONData cantains , please show us

Comment: localJSONData contains: {"data":{"mode" : "subscribe","technologyareas":[2,8,10,54],"assettypes":["podcast","documents"]}}

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the values with data parameter [$.ajax() jquery doc link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
function postJSONData(JSONData, localMode)
    {
        var localJSONData = JSONData;
        var postMode = localMode;

         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://tt.s2.com/tmobile/subscribe-service/uid=ankit_bharat_tanna',
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:"json"
                data:  JSONData
                success: function(data){
                    alert("SECOND POST JSON DATA");
                }   // Success Function
}); // AJAX Call

        alert("POST JSON ------------> "+localJSONData +" "+postMode);
    }
```

Comment: I wrote datatype: 'xml' by mistake. Should it be application/json?

Comment: You don't need to specify the datatype, the default is ok for you.

Comment: I got it Don. would it be only "json" or "application/json"

Comment: use `dataType` as `json` alone

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `data` parameter. Moreover you need to send `json` data so `dataType` parameter should be set to `json`. Below is an Example

```
function postJSONData(JSONData, localMode)
        {
            var localJSONData = JSONData;
            var postMode = localMode;

             $.ajax({
                    data: localJSONData,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://tt.s2.com/tmobile/subscribe-service/uid=ankit_bharat_tanna',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("SECOND POST JSON DATA");
                    }   // Success Function
    }); // AJAX Call

            alert("POST JSON ------------> "+localJSONData +" "+postMode);
        }
```